# Can Rails Simple Form checkbox label change depending on the checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

I'm new to Rails and not sure if I could have 2 values for the Simple Form checkbox label and change it depending whether the checkbox gets checked. Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use javascript to dynamically change the form.

```
//with jQuery
var checkbox = $("#theCheckboxId");
checkbox.change(function(event) {
    var checkbox = event.target;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        //Checkbox has been checked
    } else {
        //Checkbox has been unchecked
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. But is there another way to do it without js? I'm only applying that to one checkbox label.

Comment: I couldn't figure out the solution to modify the Simple_Form structure. I ended up using css instead. I manually created the `label` tag wrapping the checkbox and remove the label by changing `boolean_style` to `:inline`. Then created another two `<span/>` containing the two different labels and toggle its visibility by using the `:checked` pseudo-class and general sibling combinator css selector. Not sure if that's the best solution but works for me.